# For loop in javascript object

Tags: javascript

Maybe I'm really tried but not sure why this is not working, I'm trying to get back the correct value from the var object

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var EFPStart = form.formData.plantSample[i].EFPStart;
            console.log(EFPStart);
            $('#PO-'+i+'-EFP-start').val(EFPStart);
        }(i));
    }
```

and here is the 
form data

```
formData: 
  plantSample1: 
    CE: 0EFAEnd:1
    EFAStart: 1
    EFPEnd: 1
    EFPStart: 1
plantSample2: 
    CE: 0EFAEnd:1
    EFAStart: 1
    EFPEnd: 1
    EFPStart: 1
 plantSample3: 
    CE: 0EFAEnd:1
    EFAStart: 1
    EFPEnd: 1
    EFPStart: 1
```

Comment: Ok, what does "not working" mean? Do you get the wrong value, and if so, which value did you expect? Error messages?

Comment: Also, it's a bit hard to tell what the actual structure of the data is. Could you paste it in valid JavaScript instead?

Comment: You have to use bracket notation to access the members of the object - `form.formData["plantSample" + i].EFPStart`

Comment: Remember Javascript array has first element with index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just for completeness...)

In this case you have to use bracket notation to access the member of the `formData` object. The use of a closure isn't necessary.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var EFPStart = form.formData["plantSample" + i].EFPStart;
    console.log(EFPStart);
    $('#PO-' + i + '-EFP-start').val(EFPStart);
}
```